# Поток в C перезаписывает данные,внесенные предыдущим потоком

Tags: c, многопоточность, pthread, posix

у меня возникла проблема,над которой я бьюсь уже долгое время и не могу ее решить.Суть заключается в следующем:
Имеется сервер, который для каждого нового подключения запускает свой собственный поток, передавая туда указатель на структуру,в которой хранится массив указателей,указатель на текущий ip клиента и id соккета.  При принятии соединения от клиента, я записываю в структуру значение текущего ip пользователя и передаю эту структуру,как аргумент, созданному потоку. Внутри потока есть условие, где в случае равенства ip клиента "192.168.2.128" значение этого ip записывается в массив [3], в случае равенства ip клиента "192.168.2.129" значение этого ip записывается в массив [4]. В итоге,когда подключается первый клиент (128), он записывает свой ip в ячейку [3],а когда подключается второй клиент(129), он записывает свой ip в ячейку [4] и перезаписывает ячейку [3] значением своего ip, в итоге выходит так,как показано на скриншоте. [image: cам скриншот]

Прошу помочь мне разобраться,почему это происходит и как исправить.
С Уважением, Martin

Код Сервера:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>    //strlen
#include<stdlib.h>    //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include<unistd.h>    //write
#include<pthread.h> //for threading , link with lpthread
#define MAX_USERS 10

struct someArgs_tag {
    int client_sock;
    char* current_ip;
    char* massiv[10];

};

typedef struct someArgs_tag someArgs_t;

void *connection_handler(void * arg);

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc , client_sock , sizeof_client;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(3425);

    //Bind
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        //print the error message
        perror("Bind failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Bind done");

    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc , MAX_USERS);

    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    sizeof_client = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    someArgs_t args;  //инициализация структуры передаваемого аргумента

    for (int i=0;i<MAX_USERS;i++)
    {
      // Инициализирую каждый элемент массива значением "NULL"
      args.massiv[i] = "NULL";
    }

    while( (client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&sizeof_client) ) )
    {
        pthread_t thread_id;
        args.client_sock = client_sock; //записываем в структуру значение соккета
        args.current_ip = inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr); //Получение ip-адреса клиента,как указатель на строку

        printf("Cоединение принято от клента с ip = %s\n",args.current_ip);
        printf("Обрабатывает поток номер %d\n",thread_id);

        if( pthread_create( &thread_id , NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) &args) < 0)
        {
            perror("Could not create thread");
            return 1;
        }
        puts("Поток назначен");
    }

    if (client_sock < 0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

void *connection_handler(void *args)
{

    //Get the socket descriptor
    someArgs_t *arg = (someArgs_t*) args;

    int sock = arg->client_sock;
    int read_size;
    char* message , client_message[2000];

    char* current_user_ip = arg->current_ip;


    if(strcmp(current_user_ip,"192.168.2.128") == 0)
    {
      arg->massiv[3] = current_user_ip;
    }
    if(strcmp(current_user_ip,"192.168.2.129")==0)
    {
      arg->massiv[4] = current_user_ip;

    }
    for(int i=0; i<MAX_USERS; i++)
    {
      // Вывод значений элементов массива
    printf("%s\n",arg->massiv[i]);
    }

    //Receive a message from client
    while( (read_size = recv(sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
    {
            client_message[read_size] = '\0';
        write(sock , client_message , strlen(client_message));
            memset(client_message, 0, 2000);
    }

    if(read_size == 0)
    {
        puts("Client disconnected");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    else if(read_size == -1)
    {
        perror("recv failed");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Код клиента:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h> // for open
#include <unistd.h> // for close
#include <arpa/inet.h>

char message[1024];
char buf[sizeof(message)];

int main()
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sock < 0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(3425); // или любой другой порт...
    inet_aton("192.168.2.128", &addr.sin_addr);
    // addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(internet);



    if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("connect");
        exit(2);
    }

    fgets(message,1024,stdin);
    send(sock, message, sizeof(message), 0);

    recv(sock, buf, sizeof(message), 0);
    printf("%s",buf);

    close(sock);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я бы начал решение Вашей проблемы с добавления мьютексов для синхронизации потоков. Потоки изменяют `args`, при этом `args` не является атомарным типом, что вызывает неопределённое поведение: [ссылка](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/memory_model)

Comment: @ВЛ80, сейчас я обращаюсь к args из второго потока не одновременно с первым,а только тогда,когда первый завершился и клиент отключился. То есть по сути,я обращаюсь к данным,за которые никто не борется. Mutex поможет блокировать данные в условиях конкуренции, но у меня возникает проблема даже в отсутствии таковой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `connection_handler` происходит манипуляция указателями.

```
if(strcmp(current_user_ip,"192.168.2.128") == 0)
{
  arg->massiv[3] = current_user_ip;
}
if(strcmp(current_user_ip,"192.168.2.129")==0)
{
  arg->massiv[4] = current_user_ip;
}
```

Заметьте, что `arg->massiv[3]`и `arg->massiv[4]` являются указателями на один и тот же участок памяти. То есть они указывают на IP адрес последнего подключившегося клиента.

Когда подключается новый клиент, то `arg->current_ip` перезаписывается.

Чтобы исправить это, можно копировать строки. Попробуйте так:

```
arg->massiv[3] = strdup(current_user_ip);
```

(Я не проверял работоспособность этого кода).

Учтите, что `strdup` выделяет память, которую нужно будет освободить с помощью

```
free(arg->massiv[3]);
```

когда она будет более не нужна.

Comment: Спасибо Вам, это действительно помогло. Я не обратил внимание на то,что по сути в arg->massiv[3] и arg->massiv[4] хранится один и тот же указатель.